# TypeError [ERR_NO_ICU] when using the Angular CLI

Tags: angular-cli

I installed the angular cli with `sudo npm install -g @angular/cli` on my Mac (10.15.7).

But know I get the following error:

```sh
~/Workspace % ng new angular-10-app
Unknown error: TypeError [ERR_NO_ICU]: "fatal" option is not supported on Node.js compiled without ICU
```

Same error on windows, but only in command line (cmd.exe). Same command in power shell works.

```
>ng serve
Unknown error: TypeError [ERR_NO_ICU]: "fatal" option is not supported on Node.js compiled without ICU
```

Comment: You have GraalVM 20+ installed i guess. And this is the problem. Try to "sdk install java <<some_other_version>>", use it as default. Then "brew reinstall node", and again "npm i -g @angular/cli". Maybe some steps here are not needed, but this exact thing here worked for me.

Comment: Same i had uninstall GraalVm and now everything works again : sdk uninstall java 21.0.0.r11-grl or sdk uninstall java 21.0.0.r8-grl

Comment: Hi,
How do I know if GraalVM is installed, and which version am I using?

Comment: You might still need GraalVM, so uninstalling it is not a solution. The problem occurs because there's a skimmed compiled version of node and ng inside GraalVM installed by sdkman and the path to sdkman is always added later to your $PATH variable! So the system takes that first when you call it… The solution would be make a symlink from the path where node and ng is installed on system to a more recent one on $PATH like ~/.local/bin